# SocketException was unhandled when connecting to a database

Tags: mysql, .net

```
using System;
using MySql.Data.MySqlClient;
namespace test2 {
    class Program {
        static void Main(string[] args) {
            string connectionString =  "Server=localhost;Database=login;Uid=root;Pwd=TheDarkest;";
            MySqlConnection connection = new MySqlConnection(connectionString);
            connection.Open();
        }
    }
}
```

## [image]

The exception occurs at `connection.Open()`. I cannot seems to find the solution though I looked everywhere.

Btw I can connect to the database using python.

Answer (score 0):

Add **try/catch block** until database connection is closed in your code.

Like ,

```
     static void Main(string[] args) {
      try{
        ......
        string connectionString ="Server=localhost;Database=login;Uid=root;Pwd=TheDarkest;"; 
        MySqlConnection connection = new MySqlConnection(connectionString);
        connection.Open();
       .......
      } 
      catch(Exception e)
      {
        ....
      }
```

Comment: yeah i did that earlier but the moment the codes read **connection.Open()** it throws an exception and goes straight to **catch** which do not help me connect

Comment: then why u didnt show try catch in your sample code

Comment: i looked for a solution everywhere and tried different things which consisted of the try catch and changing the connectionString and slightly different code. but still no positive result

Comment: have u specified port number in your connection string ? and also check whether URL is right

Comment: i specified the port to 3306 and the url is right but still the same :/